# How to boot OpenBSD ISO in UEFI mode in VirtualBox?

Tags: boot, virtualbox, openbsd

The latest OpenBSD ISO image [install64.iso](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq4.html#Download) does not seem to boot in UEFI mode in the latest version of VirtualBox. However, I believe OpenBSD should be able to do this. I tried this simply by creating a new VM instance and then turning on UEFI in the settings:

[image]

What I get is the generic EFI boot screen which is shown when booting into the OS doesn't work:

[image]

It does work if I turn off EFI.

Do I need to do something more to get OpenBSD to boot in EFI mode?

Answer (score 2):

You could download the install64.fs and convert it to VDI format. Attach this disk as second disk to your vm and install the openbsd system from there.

```
VBoxManage convertdd Downloads/install64.fs install64.vdi --format VDI
```

I tested it and it worked for me.

Comment: to users of later openbsd version (tested on 6.9), it's .img file not .fs file anymore but this still works